# Enhance MySQL search with FULLTEXT index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I would like to improve the results from my Fulltext query.

```
SELECT *, MATCH (winery) AGAINST ('chateau cheval blanc') AS score
FROM usr_wines
WHERE MATCH (winery) AGAINST ('chateau cheval blanc')
ORDER BY score DESC
...
```

The problem is the results shown are like this:

- chateau cheval blanc petit cheval
- chateau cheval blanc

I think MySQL returns "chateau cheval blanc petit cheval" before the other one because it found 2 occurrences of "cheval" in the string.
But for me, the second result should be displayed before the first because it matched more exactly what is queried.

I tried other things, such "WITH QUERY EXPANSION" and "IN BOOLEAN MODE" without success. I also read we can add signs (+) in the search to change behaviours.

Well, any help is welcome to obtain the appropriate behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

You just have to use IN BOOLEAN MODE with **"**  to indicate that you want exact phrase.
Example :

```
SELECT *, MATCH (winery) AGAINST ('"chateau cheval blanc"'  IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM usr_wines
WHERE MATCH (winery) AGAINST ('"chateau cheval blanc"'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC
```